# Google Drive integration in iOS to upload PDF file

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, google-drive-api

I am developing an app in iOS 8 and I have integrated Google Drive by installing the following pods:

```
pod platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Drive', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.0'
```

When I place code to upload a PDF file, I am getting the following errors:

> 1. Property 'title' not found on object of type 'GTLDriveFile *'
> 2. Use of undeclared identifier 'GTLDriveParentReference'.
> 3. No known class method for selector 'queryForFilesInsertWithObject:uploadParameters:'.

This is my code:

```
GTLDriveFile *driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];

driveFile.mimeType = @"application/pdf";
driveFile.originalFilename = @"database.pdf";
driveFile.name = @"database.pdf";
driveFile.size = fileSizeNumber;
NSString *parentId = @"root";
driveFile.parents = @[parentId];

NSData *fileContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"application/pdf"];


GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = folderIdentifier; // identifier property of the folder
driveFile.parents = @[ parentRef ];

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:driveFile uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.service executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                  GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                  NSError *error) {
                  if (error == nil) {
                      NSLog(@"\n\nfile uploaded into google drive\\<my_folder> foler");
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"\n\nfile uplod failed google drive\\<my_folder> foler");            
                  }
              }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `driveFile.name` instead of `driveFile.title`
2. There's no `GTLDriveParentReference` class, so remove these lines.
3. Use `queryForFilesCreateWithObject` instead of `queryForFilesInsertWithObject`

Comment: thank you for solving 1st error .can you please let me know about other two

Comment: 2. There's no GTLDriveParentReference class, so remove these lines.

Comment: 3. Use `queryForFilesCreateWithObject` instead of `queryForFilesInsertWithObject`

Comment: thank you so much . i have one more question i am trying to upload pdf bt it gives me this error can u please help me out Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.)" UserInfo={error=The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable., NSLocalizedFailureReason=(The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.)

Comment: i have edited my code can you please check and let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have created perfect method to upload PDF file over google drive in iOS

```
-(void)sharePDFFileOnGoogleDrive{
GTLServiceDrive *driveService;
driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
driveService.authorizer = self.authToken;
GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
metadata.originalFilename = @"pdf-sample.pdf";
metadata.title = @"PDF file Name";
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf-sample" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSString *mimeType = @"application/pdf";
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:file
                                                                                   MIMEType:mimeType];
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:metadata
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
    }];
}
```